# Is a prepareForSegue notify a view controller when a segue is about to preform to another view controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Up until now I have used `prepareForSegue` method to notify a view controller he is about to review a segue from a different view controller, but if i'm the vc that sending the segue, will my prepareForSegue (in he same class of the segue sender) will check if there is a code to preform before he fires the segue?

I'm asking because I got a solution here to preform a simple segue just to go from stable view row which represent notes to the creation page of the note for editing...very simple, but from some reason it's not presenting my note in the creation page, only takes me to a new clean creation page..

So I though maybe it's because the prepareForSegue method..here you can see the question to give you more details [How to to create a segue to push back to editing mode from a table view?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22798498/3412425)

Would really appreciate to get your help on this.

This are the 2 methods I added to my NotesList table view controller:

```
#pragma mark - delegate

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"noteSegue" sender:nil];
}


- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

{
    if ([[segue identifier]  isEqualToString:@"noteSegue"]) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NMNote *note = [self.notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NMCreateNotesViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
        destination.textField.text = note.content;
    }
}
```

And I made sure the segue identifier in the storyboard is named noteSegue. So why its note working...Im getting a new TextView instead of populating it with the note content :/

This is the error i'm getting:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `prepareForSegue:` method is called on the **current** VC not the destination. [UIViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue%3asender%3a). You can use the method to obtain a reference to the destination VC and set variables/call methods on it before the segue is performed.

Calling the segue like this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NAMEOFSEGUE" sender:nil];
```

You can then prepare the destination VC like this:

```
#import "NMCreateNotesViewController.h"

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"NAMEOFSEGUE"]) {
        NMCreateNotesViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
        [destination createNote]; /* or something similar */
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NMNote *note = [self.notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"noteSegue" sender:note];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"NAMEOFSEGUE"]) {
        NMCreateNotesViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
         NMnote *note = (NMNote*) sender;
         destination.textField.text = note.content;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ashley, I added some code to the question in the end, from some reason it's still not working for me...please help figure this out its driving me nuts heh. thanks!

Comment: Modified my answer. Also you used did DEselect not didSelect. I make the same mistake all the time (I blame xCode's auto-completion)

Comment: heh yeah this mistakes are annoying :/ I did implemented your suggestion, I definitely understand the logic behind it, but another SIGABRT error now, I added a screenshot of the error..thanks :) @Ashley

Answer (score 0):

To check if there is a code to preform before the segue you can use solution below:

```
if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]) {
        UIViewController *nextVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        if(nextVC respondsToSelector:@selector(yourMethod)){
              [nextVC yourMethod];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you are sure to perform the specific segue by implementing this method

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your note presenting code in `viewDidLoad`, try moving that to `viewDidAppear` (in your note editing VC).  There used to be an issue when presenting from a `TableView` row where the segue would fire after VDL was executed.